# after upgrading to Lubuntu 17.10 screen became black for 3/4 of surface

Tags: upgrade, screen, intel

I'm a long term user of Lubuntu and in the last years I've always found here tons of answers to my questions, but today I'm not able to solve my trouble.
After upgrading from Lubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 from a usb live (that was working properly), the first reboot came to an almost full black screen. Screen was black from left side to aprox 3/4 of the wide, I could see only a column on the right side of the monitor, showing the power button.
My computer is an old Asus eee pc 1005 with 2 gb ram that works as an amazing donkey. [here a screen shot of system informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFRel.png) 
I though this could come by some bugs in upgrading, so I've downloaded the new lubuntu 17.10 iso and I've installed it erasing previous release. After rebooting, I had the same problem.
I've followed instruction to enter the Grub and add nomodeset. This did not fix the issue.
Now I'm running a Linux Lite release (that is ok) but I miss my best friend Lubuntu!! If you have some idea on how I can try it again, please let me know!
Thank you
Giulio

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with Intel drivers in 4.13 kernel, workaround is to downgrade to 4.12 until a fix is released. Having same issue on EEE PC 901.

For more information view these bug reports (and maybe subscribe to them for updates):

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102929

https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/1724639

There is a claim that one linked patch fixes the problem, now we wait until it gets pushed upstream.

If for some reason you have trouble downgrading comment and I'll try to help with that too. Two more tips:

1. **Update:** New workaround, I haven't tested yet is to use `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text`
2. The affected area is the same as the GRUB screen size, reducing it will reduce disabled area:

   `sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   sudo update-grub`
3. Use recovery mode meanwhile if you don't already. But that will reduce screen resolution.

Comment: @Julio there is a new workaround and a Launchpad report link

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Suspend(one of the possible options behind the power button in right upper corner) and awake again, display will work.